# Fuzzy matching column with right names of a list

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy

I have dataframe column with typos.

| ID | Banknane |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bank of America |
| 2 | bnk of America |
| 3 | Jp Morg |
| 4 | Jp Morgan |

And I have a list with the right names of the banks.

```
["Bank of America", "JPMorgan Chase]
```

I want to check and replace wrong banknames with the right names of the list with the help of levenshtein distance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way to do it using Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, which provides helpers for computing deltas.

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# Define a helper function
def match(x, values, threshold):
    def ratio(a, b):
        return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

    results = {
        value: ratio(value, x) for value in values if ratio(value, x) > threshold
    }
    return max(results, key=results.get) if results else x
```

And then:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Bankname": ["Bank of America", "bnk of America", "Jp Morg", "Jp Morgan"],
    }
)

names = ["Bank of America", "JPMorgan Chase"]

df["Bankname"] = df["Bankname"].apply(lambda x: match(x, names, 0.4))
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   ID         Bankname
0   1  Bank of America
1   2  Bank of America
2   3   JPMorgan Chase
3   4   JPMorgan Chase
```

Of course, you can replace the inner `ratio` function with any other more appropriated sequence matcher.